# When turning expressions to input strings, is it possible to make scientific notations of large integers stay unchanged?

Tags: string-manipulation

```
In[144]:= ToString[1*^8 f[2.53 x],InputForm]
Out[144]= 100000000*f[2.53*x]

In[152]:= ToString[123*^6 f[2.53 x], InputForm]

Out[152]= "123000000*f[2.53*x]"
```

Is there a way to keep the nicer form of `1*^8` and `123*^6` which I believe anyway is closer to how I'd input such expressions?

Comment: Perhaps helpful [280609](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280609/scientific-output-format-for-integers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would implement @MichaelE2's idea:

```
Unprotect[Integer];
Clear[Integer]

Format[i_Integer, InputForm] /; !TrueQ@$IntegerShortHand := Block[
    {$IntegerShortHand = True, z = IntegerExponent[i]},

    SequenceForm[i 10^-z,OutputForm["*^"], z] /; z>2
]

Protect[Integer];
```

Then:

```
ToString[1234000000*f[2.5*x]+345*^7+f[7890], InputForm]
```

> ```
> "345*^7 + f[7890] + 1234*^6*f[2.5*x]"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there ought to be a better way:

```
altToString[expr_] := Module[{intForm},
   StringTake[
    StringReplace[
     ToString[Hold[expr] /. x_Integer :> intForm[x], InputForm],
     ToString[intForm] ~~ "[" ~~ n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "]" :> 
      StringJoin@ Replace[
        Characters[n],
        {x__, y : "0" ...} /; Length[{y}] > 2 :> 
          {{x}, "*^", ToString@Length[{y}]}]
     ],
    {6, -2}]
   ];

altToString[1234000000*f[2.5*x] + 345*^7 + f[7890]]
(*  "345*^7 + f[7890] + 1234*^6*f[2.5*x]"  *)
```

On the other hand, I hate formatting numbers. I can never find a way to do it that seems easier than doing it by hand with pencil and paper.

`Length[{y}] > 2` in the code defines the cut-off for converting trailing zeros to the `*^n` format.

Comment: See my answer for another way to implement your idea.

Comment: @CarlWoll Nice. I thought there was something like `IntegerExponent`, but I couldn't recall/find it.

Answer (score 0):

You may define your own "ToString". E.g.:

```
myToString[in_] := Module[{ex},
  in /. x_?NumberQ :> (
     ex = Floor[Log[10, x]];
     If[ex == 0, ToString[x, InputForm], 
      ToString[x/10^ex // N, InputForm] ~~ 
       "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(*\)]\)^" ~~ ToString[ex]])
  ]
```

With this:

```
myToString[100000000*f[2.53*x]]
myToString[123*^6 f[2.53 x]]
```

[image]

Comment: (1) It does not achieve the desired output for integers. (2) I expected sci. not. here but not the roundoff error: `myToString[123*^6 f[0.53 x]]` --> ` "1.23\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\ \), \(*\)]\)^8" f["5.300000000000001\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\ \), \(*\)]\)^-1" x]`. (3) The output of `myToString[]` is not a string. (4) Why the `SuperscriptBox[]`? That's not in the standard input syntax.